# sbt aggregate coverage reports for unit and integration tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, integration-testing, scoverage

I use the `sbt` plugin [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) to generate test coverage reports for my scala project. However, I'm unable to combine the test reports for unit tests and integration tests.

Here are the commands I run

```
sbt coverage test // to run unit tests
sbt coverage it:test // to run integration tests
sbt coverageReport // to generate coverage report
```

In the case above, I only get the coverage report for integration tests.

**Question**

- How do I generate a report that aggregates results from both the unit tests as well as the integration tests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just should work (I've just tested on dummy project).
BTW, you can combine all tasks in one call `sbt coverage test it:test coverageReport`.
I cannot help you without seeing your project.

Comment: How did you configure the scoverage for scala using SBT ? I need to do it for my project from scratch. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was running `sbt clean` after running the unit tests and before running the integration tests.

So, the commands as listed above, should generate the combined coverage report.